# How can I use my gpu cards over LAN for gaming?

Tags: lan, gpu, remote, gaming

I have a computer setup that has 3X RTX 3070 and an RTX 3060.

My kids have two USFF computers in which I cannot add any GPU (to small case and not enough power because of a small PSU).

How can I make the GPU available over LAN so they can play games using graphics rendering from my computer?

Comment: LAN latency at best is orders of magnitude worse than typical CPU <-> GPU latency. I think it would destroy performance. I think you'd be better off letting them VNC (a.k.a screen share, remote desktop) into your computer and run their game there so you can keep the game code on the CPU tightly coupled with the GPU.

Comment: I already tried remote desktop multiple times, but a their most favorite game Minecraft is impossible to play. The screen is stuck for a few milli seconds and when you move to look around it goes so fast, this makes it impossible to play using rdp protocols.

Comment: Remote desktop protocols are far lower bandwidth and less sensitive to latency than the interconnection between a system's CPU/RAM and its GPU. So if remote desktop was unplayably bad, going to remote GPU seems like it would be a leap in the wrong direction.

Comment: Ok, do you have any ideas on how to setup something like a cloud gaming server?

Answer (score 0):

(I cannot comment due to a lack of reputation points.)

Over LAN, Steam Link or Moonlight would be your best bet for streaming games from your setup to the kids' USFFs, rather than RDP/VNC.

Since there are multiple GPUs, VMs with GPU pass-through might be worth considering to isolate the kids activities from the rest of the system.

This would be the closest one gets to using a GPU over LAN; alternatively, consider an external GPU enclosure connected directly to the respective USFF in which to place one of those GPUs.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, but thanks for your answer. I didn't want to work with steam, but Moonlight looks promising. I will check it out.

Comment: The external gpu enclosure is a no go, it's to expensive, for the price of the enclosure I can buy another pc the has the option to add any gpu I already have.